# Why does this URL-matching regex break at the equal sign?

Tags: regex

A module in our application checks status updates written by users for URLs, in order to get a preview from embed.ly. Everything seemed to work fine until the following link was shared:

http://sic.sapo.pt/proj_queridajulia/Scripts/VideoPlayer.aspx?videoId={C1BB1496-A37B-44B7-825C-78A9A0A0B9AE}

I copied our regex (not written by me) and the link into http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and apparently the regex only matches up to the equal sign. The regex is:

```
(^|[ \t\r\n])((ftp|http|https|gopher|mailto|news|nntp|telnet|wais|file|prospero|aim|webcal):(([A-Za-z0-9$_.+!*(),;/?:@&~=-])|%[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}){2,}(#([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9$_.+!*(),;/?:@&~=%-]*))?([A-Za-z0-9$_+!*();/?:~-]))
```

Can somebody help me and point out where the error lies, or recommend another, preferably bullet-proof URL matching regex?

Comment: tried escaping the equal sign? i.e change "=" to "\="

Comment: Ok, just solved it. I just added curly braces to all groups of parentesis in the regex, turning it into: (^|[ \t\r\n])((ftp|http|https|gopher|mailto|news|nntp|telnet|wais|file|prospero|aim|webcal):(([A-Za-z0-9$_.+!*(){},;/?:@&~=-])|%[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}){2,}(#([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9$_.+!(){},;/?:@&~=%-]))?([A-Za-z0-9$_+!*(){};/?:~-]))

Comment: Should have tried that before posting the question. Thanks for input dutt, anyway.

Comment: There's gotta be an easier regex than this monster... O_o;;

Comment: Since you found an answer to your own question, rather than posting the solution in a comment, you should instead [post the answer to your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking). Then others can help you decide whether your answer is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just experimented around and got it to work. I added curly braces to what seems to be groups of allowed characters. The final regex turned into this:

(^|[ \t\r\n])((ftp|http|https|gopher|mailto|news|nntp|telnet|wais|file|prospero|aim|w‌​ebcal):(([A-Za-z0-9$_.+!*(){},;/?:@&~=-])|%[A-Fa-f0-9]{2}){2,}(#([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA‌​-Z0-9$*.+!(){},;/?:@&~=%-]))?([A-Za-z0-9$*+!*(){};/?:~-]))

I still have no idea of what part of the regex is responsible for what. :/ So if somebody feels like pointing out, I would appreciate it.